# Rails 4 Create form to update only one attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a user model, but I need to create a form to update only one attribute.

EDIT: I added the `create_mailbox` patch in `:users` resource but the form throws a `undefined method`settings_create_mailbox_path'` error.  Can anyone give me some insight to how this member patch/resource routes work?

Here's the form:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: settings_create_mailbox_path(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :rss_mailbox, autocomplete: 'off'%>
  <button type="submit" class="button">Create Mailbox</button>
<% end %>
```

Here's the Users route:

```
resources :users, id: /.*/ do
    member do
      patch :settings_update, controller: :settings
      patch :create_mailbox, controller: :settings
      patch :view_settings_update, controller: :settings
      patch :sharing_services_update, controller: :sharing_services
      patch :actions_update, controller: :actions
    end
  end
```

And here's the settings route:

```
get :settings, to: 'settings#settings'
  namespace :settings do
    get :account
    get :billing
    get :import_export
    get :feeds
    get :help
    post :update_credit_card
    post :mark_favicon_complete
    post :update_plan
    post :font
    post :font_increase
    post :font_decrease
    post :entry_width
  end
```

Comment: check the output of `rake routes`. Your path is named wrong in your view.

Comment: Thanks, the name of the route is: `create_mailbox_user` not settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was using the wrong route name. This was the right one:

```
create_mailbox_user_path
```

Answer (score 2):

It would depend on the attribute and what you're changing it to.

If it's a simple toggling of a boolean field, for example, you could get away with a link that fires off an ajax request, that makes the change and returns some HTML (eg. to update the link you clicked).

If it's something else, eg. a text field or a string or something, a `form_for @user` would be the typical way. But the form would only have one field, and the controller that processes the form post would have its strong parameters (or attr_accessible for Rails 3) set so that it will only accept data for that one field.

Answer (score -1):

Rails 4 Use [Strong Parameters](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters) to determine which attribute is allow to update like so:

```
def user_param
  params.require(:user).permit(:attr)
end
```